# Can $f[g(x)]$ and $g[f(x)]$ be used to prove that a function is onto?

Tags: functions, relations

I am very confused as to whether we can use  $f[g(x)]$ and $g[f(x)]$ to show that a function is onto.

Let's say I have a function :

$y = f(x) = x + 1$
from $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

Is it possible that if I find $f[g(x)]$ and $g[f(x)]$ and they give one $y$ and one $x$ (i.e., $f[g(x)] = y$ and $g[f(x)] = x$)
then my function will be onto?

Sometimes this method did worked but other times even though I got one $y$ and one $x$, the function turned out to be not onto.

Kindly explain.
Thanks

Comment: what does onto mean?

Comment: It means Surjective function

Comment: @Baazigar What exactly do you mean by "I find f[g(x)] and g[f(x)] and they give one y and one x"?

Comment: I meant that f[g(x)]  = y and g[f(x)]  = x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\circ g$ is "onto" (surjective), then $f$ must be onto.

**Proof**: Let $f:X\to Y, g:Z\to X$, and suppose $f\circ g$ is onto. Let $y\in Y$ be an arbitrary element. As $f\circ g$ is onto, then there is $z\in Z$ such that $(f\circ g)(z)=f(g(z))=y$. But then $f(x)=y$ if you set $x=g(z)$. In other words, for every $y\in Y$ you can find $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. This proves that $f$ is onto.

Comment: So.. the thing I asked is True?

Comment: @Baazigar Yes, if you can find a function $g$ and prove that $x\mapsto f(g(x))$ is onto, this automatically proves that $f$ is onto.

Comment: In my question.. I would do it like this : x = y - 1 = g(x). So fog(x) = f(y-1) = y - 1 + 1 = y.

Comment: @Baazigar Indeed. For $g(x)=x-1$, you have $f(g(x))=(x-1)+1=x$ which is obviously "onto" (each $x$ maps to itself), so $f$ is then "onto".

Comment: But this method fails sometimes.

Comment: @Baazigar If you can demonstrate to me one case where it fails, I will be happy to analyse it for you and check why it fails.

Comment: Let f:N→N be defined by f(n)= { (n+1) / 2 if n is odd ; n/2 if n is even

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117858/discussion-between-baazigar-and-stinking-bishop).